# ios swift: return to previous view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

from a dynamic `tableView` "CardSets" I do a segue to a static `tableView` "AddCardSet" to enter some data. After successfull `save()` method I want to send the user back to the initial `tableView` "CardSets". How can I do that?

Do I have to set a segue onto the `save` button? Or is there a shorter way?

Comment: Why do I get a downvote here? What Didi I do wrong?

Comment: Some just want to watch the world burn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `popViewControllerAnimated`:

```
if let navigationController = self.navigationController
{
    navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: this works for me! Thanks! One further question, how do I force the tableView "CardSets" to reload at the moment I return?

Comment: You can overload `viewWillAppear` in in the other view controller. This is called whenever the view is added to the hierarchy.

Comment: like this?
`override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }`
It wont work for me :( there is no reload

Comment: Hm, is it called at all? And don't forget to call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`. Have also a look at [I need to refresh the content of a view as soon as I popViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2597421/172695)

Answer (score 1):

the best answer is to create A singltone like this :

for example :

class Collage {

```
var classes: [Class] = []
static var collageSharedInsttance : Collage? = nil

static func GetSharedInstance() -> Collage {
    if collageSharedInsttance == nil {
        collageSharedInsttance = Collage()
    }

    return collageSharedInsttance!
}
```

}

and Access your data from the second controller like this :

```
    var JohnBryceCollage = Collage.GetSharedInstance()
```

Answer (score -1):

The best option is to use `Unwind segue` for this case. They allow you to jump back through navigation stack. And they are independent of how your controllers are presented - modally or within `UINavigationController` stack. More of that they allow you to jump through multiple levels back.

Please check out [Apple's Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) and this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)